# how to start Leingen with java -Djavax.net.debug=true option?

Tags: ssl, clojure, leiningen

I am trying to diagnose a few issues with ssl connectivity with Leingen. I am trying to find  what SSL Key Store and Trust Store is being Used by Leingen,
 I am behind a corporate firewall and we have self signed certificates deployed on all our desktops . I am running lein.bat on a windows 10.

Hence **I have to start Leingen with java -Djavax.net.debug=true option.**

The :jvm-opts in  the project.clj  wont work -- I need to make sure the Liengen's JVM is started with this option

Answer (score 2):

You can set leiningen JVM options by setting [`LEIN_JVM_OPTS`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#setting-jvm-options) environment variable before running `lein` in the same terminal session.

Answer (score 0):

The `lein` command is just a shell script which eventually invokes `java` with various options.  You can edit this script to see what options are used and/or to modify them.

As Piotrek mentioned, the `LEIN_JVM_OPTS` environment variable is the canonical way of passing options to the jvm in which `lein` runs.  You can see it used on [line 372](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/bin/lein#L371) of the source code.

For your case:

```
> export LEIN_JVM_OPTS='-Djavax.net.debug=true'
> lein clean
> lein run
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running windows, you'll want to actually look at the [lein.bat](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/bin/lein.bat) file. You'll still need to update LEIN_JVM_OPTS, but how you go about it will be a bit different. If you're using windows command terminal (cmd.exe) you will want to use the `set` command.

```
set LEIN_JVM_OPTS="-Djavax.net.debug=true"
```

The command is likely different if you're using powershell, and you can likely find out how to set that on this page on [environment variables](http://xahlee.info/mswin/env_var.html).